# Installing same application with multiple installers through WIX

Tags: windows, wix

I have a windows application, for which I create a bootstrapper (EXE) from an MSI. At the same time, I have another executable, that installs several components, one of which is my original MSI. Is there someway to gracefully handle this so that running the different installers on top of each other recognizes that the same component is being installed?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that in your other exe/meta installer, you would like to detect if the msi package is already installed, if so, skip launching this MSI package.

What kind of a meta installer/bootstrapper is it? The best approach to detect if the msi package is already installed is to make use of windows installer API's.

The following are two API's which can aid you in this exercise:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370103(v=vs.85).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370131(v=vs.85).aspx

If this does not help you ,kindy let us know the kind of Meta Installer/bootstrapper that you are using and then we can discuss further about it.

Hope this helps.